# Poisson's equation with a sinusoidal source

Tags: elliptic-pde

I have an embarrassingly basic question that I am, well, embarrassed to be asking.

Let's say I want to solve Poisson's equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions on the domain $\Omega = [-1, 1]\times[-1, 1]$. I want to do so for a sinusoidal source,

$\nabla^2 u = \sin(x)\sin(y)$ where $u = u(x, y)$.

Is there a way to do this without using Fourier series? I must admit, I haven't been solving many PDE's analytically recently, and have been a bit spoiled by ODE's where I can simply guess the solution. I do feel, however, that this is a simple question with a simple answer that I should see right away.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized there's also the math stack exchange - I think this question is more suitable for over there and can be removed.

Comment: Unless there is some coefficient missing, this is going to be messy even with Fourier series, as the size of the domain doesn't match any multiple of the period of the source. But if they do match, using Fourier series is equivalent to guessing, more or less.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I was sitting there thinking it should be easy, but that explains why I couldn't easily come up with a solution, and had to resort to Fourier series. I need to brush up on my PDE's - I guess it's been seven years now since I took a proper PDE class.